# trigger unobtrusive validation but prevent submit on mvc4 form

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, unobtrusive-validation

I have a form, this form has some values that are required, so in my viewmodel I have some things like:

```
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Res_Errors), ErrorMessageResourceName = "errorPacienteNoSeleccionado")]
public int? scheduledIdPersonaSeleccionada { get; set; }
```

as well as a submit button, but I don't want to submit the form to the server, I only need to execute a jquery function if my validation passes.

The validation is working but I don't know how to prevent the form from posting and instead call my function.

Comment: maybe you should be using `@Ajax.BeginForm`?

Comment: Without some kind of JavaScript intervention, the normal process is to submit the data to the server. At least with Ajax.BeginForm you can call javascript code on "submit".

Answer (score 2):

if you only want to execute javascript on form submit (and not *actually* send the information) have a look at [`@Ajax.BeginForm`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxextensions.beginform%28v=vs.108%29.aspx):

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions { OnBegin = "MyFunction" }))
{
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.scheduledIdPersonaSeleccionado)
    <input type="submit" value="Presentar" />
}
```

Alternatively you can hook in to the submit event and do it yourself:

```
$('form').submit(function(){
  if ($(this).valid()) { // validation passed
    // cal your jquery function here
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your submit button to button type. Validation will call, but submit won't

```
<form>
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.scheduledIdPersonaSeleccionado)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x=>x.scheduledIdPersonaSeleccionado)
    <input type="button" value="Presentar" onclick="DoSomething();" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by hacking through [jQuery Validate default options](https://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.setDefaults/). jQuery Validate is used under the hood by unobtrusive validation.

If you have only one form to validate on the page, you can define globally a submit handler which will execute only when a valid form is submitted:

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
    submitHandler: function (form, e) {
        // your code
    }
});
```

It has to be defined before the unobtrusive initialization, which occurs on `ready`. Or you will have to re-parse the form with `$.validator.unobtrusive.parse(selectorOfYourForm)`.

In my case, having many forms with different needs, I have used something like this:

```
let submitHandlers = [];

$.validator.setDefaults({
    submitHandler: function (form, e) {
        let result = true;
        $.each(submitHandlers, function (i, submitHandler) {
            result = submitHandler(form, e) && result;
        });
        return result;
    }
});

function addUnobstrusiveValidationSubmitHandler(submitHandler) {
    if (typeof submitHandler !== 'function') {
        throw 'submitHandler must be a function';
    }
    submitHandlers.push(submitHandler);
}
```

I leave to each `submitHandler` the responsibility of working only on forms it has to handle. The submit handler should check the form, and just `return true;` without doing anything else if it is not a form it should handle. So adding a bad `submitHandler` acting on unexpected forms will mess other forms or the whole page.

It would be better if we could define the `submitHandler` in the `parse` call instead, but currently this call does not take an `options` object.

(There is also some options which can be defined globally by assigning an object to `$validator.unobtrusive.options`, but I do not find much documentation about this beyond `errorClass` and `errorElement` options, and it does not seem to have an option for specifying a `submitHandler`. As far as I can see from the source, we could only define the following additional options, matching the [jQuery validate ones](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/): `errorPlacement`, `invalidHandler` and `success`.)